# What happens half life (second) which Decay constant is $9 \times 10^{-8} s^{-1 }$

Tags: calculus, physics

I've which decay constant is $9\times10^{-8}$ s$^{-1}$ so how to find half life (second) of this element? I asked my teacher but he doesn't have enough time to solve this. If anyone helps it would be great.
$\ln2 = 0,693$

Comment: Although there is a formula based answer, please understand the basic theory. Radioactive decays are first order reactions, as evident by the units of the decay constant given in your post. Hope you derive the half life time on own now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the formula for radioactive decay.

(decay constant)=ln2/(half life)

So

$9\cdot 10^{-8}=\frac{0.693}{\left( half\; life \right)}$

$\left( half\; life \right)=\frac{0.693}{9\cdot 10^{-8}}$

Comment: You are really great!! :) thank you again